# Get QGIS 'to_date' expression function to interpret two-digit formatted year as being 21st century

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression

I have a string, which contains a date field.
eg: "19-Jan-20"

I have created a new field, which I want to store the year value, as an integer.

In the field calculator, I have used

```
year(to_date("field_name", 'dd-MMM-yy'))
```

This works great, except that the year that comes out, is '1920', not '2020'
The issue appears to be with the 'to_date' function.

My solution was to simply add 100 to the end, so it become

```
year(to_date("field_name", 'dd-MMM-yy')) + 100
```

This worked, but im just wondering if there i a more elegant solution or a setting to change somewhere. 'Default century' or something similar which would make this function work correctly.

Comment: I dont think it isnt elegant. But you could create a case when. Something like  `case when abs(year(now())-year(to_date("field_name", 'dd-MMM-yy'))) > 50 then year(to_date("field_name", 'dd-MMM-yy')) + 100`

Comment: The QGIS function https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/resources/function_help/json/to_date is using Qt function https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-2 . I believe that the function works correctly as it has been programmed in the 20th century and  that the `+100` is the best temporary solution until your data provider changes the year format to `yyyy`.

Comment: great thanks for confirming that. Who would have thought - QGIS having a Y2K bug. :p

Answer (score 2):

Extract the year in two-digit format using `right ([expression], 2)` and add 2000:

```
right ("field_name",2)+2000
```